# Can we find the redundant features in original data after applying PCA

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, pca

Thanks in advance.

We have known that PCA is used to remove some redundant, or linear-dependent feature/dimension(e.g. km and inch features) in the original data set.  Furthermore, eigenvalues in descend-order just act as a weight, telling us which new feature/dimension in the new orthogonal space is the most/least important.

However, It seems that eigenvalue has no explicit relation to the old feature/dimension in the original data set.

Here is my question, after applying PCA, can we look back, and find out the specific redundant(near-linear-dependent ) features in the original data set?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588637/matlab-how-to-find-which-variables-from-dataset-could-be-discarded-using-pca-in) is the similar question asked previously, but no exact answers is provided so far. Hence, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you don't need PCA for that. Just look at the variance in your original dimensions.